# Combining iterations to come up with a final solution

Tags: statistics, summation

For a game I'm building, I need to know how many tries it will take for a player to roll several specific numbers (say 1-30 out of 100 possible numbers). The numbers can be repeated and only need to be rolled once to count, order doesn't matter. Let's say I need a probability of at least 95%.

So I came up with the following formula for calculating each iteration:
[image: formula]

In the picture you can see how the first and last iterations look. Solving for `l` will give me the solution I need per iteration.

*The question*: How can I combine the iterations in a way that I get one final `l` value? Thanks!

**EDIT**: I Think I've solved it, here's a wolfram equation for my solution, maybe..

```
sum(log(-5/(-100+c)))/(log(1-c/100)), c=1 to 30
```

Comment: The solution you've provided doesn't make sense. For the above example it comes to to `l=1.45` which can't possibly be right.

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong $p$, it should be $p=0.7$, the probability of failure in the geometric istribution. Then (approximately)  $l=7.4$.

Comment: Yeah that would return the same as my formula above. Could you please repost the equation?

Comment: Since your equation matches mine, it seems like that would be the actual solution. If you'd like to post it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Let $q$ be the probability of "failure" in the geometric distribution with parameter $p=1-q$. So if $p=30/100$, then $q=0.7$. Your sum is the probability that there are $0$ to $30$ failures. until the first success. The complement of this event is that the first $l+1$ trials are failures. This has probability $q^{l+1}$. So we want $1-q^{l+1}=0.95$. (Usually there is no exact integer solution.) But solving the equation $q^{l+1}=0.05$, we get $(l+1)\log(q)=\log(0.05)$, so $l+1=\frac{\log(0.05)}{\log(q)}$. You seem to want a sum of the $l$, for $q=70/100$  to $99/100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%C3%A9-nicolas) for his explanation in the comments!

Let $q$ be the probability of "failure" in the geometric distribution with parameter $p=1−q$. So if $p=30/100$, then $q=0.7$.  If $l$ is a non-negative integer, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l} q^k p$$
is the probability that there are $0$ to $l$ failures until the first success.

The complement of this event is that the first $l+1$ trials are failures. This has probability $q^{l+1}$. So we want 
$$1−q^{l+1}=0.95.$$
 Usually there is no exact integer solution. But we will not be far off if we solve the equation $q^{l+1}=0.05$. Taking logarithms, we get $(l+1)\log(q)=\log(0.05)$, so 
$$l=\frac{\log(0.05)}{\log(q)}-1.$$

This matches my predicted solution as posted in the edit above, only it's actually explained instead of extrapolating a formula, so hooray for both of us!

Anyway, the final solution looks like this:

$$
\sum_{c=1}^{30} \frac{\log(0.05)}{\log(1-\frac{c}{100})}-1\tag{displayed}
$$